# How to connect an AWS RDS Database instance running on private PVC through kubectl

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

I'm trying to access remotely an AWS RDS Database instance running on private PVC through

> kubectl port-forward

The RDS database public accessiblity is set to "No",  also I have an EKS cluster running on the same RDS PVC, the pods and services of EKS are able to communicate with AWS RDS.

So far I have created below service

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: xxx-xxx.xxxxxxx.eu-xx-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

And below is the kubectl command that I have executed

```
kubectl  run -it --rm --image=postgres postgres-client  -- postgres-service --host=xx-xx.xx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com  --port=5432 --username=xxx --password=xxx --dbname=xxx
```

and the result I get is

```
error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Comment: you mean VPC i think or PVC ? in the first line of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to use kubectl you can use postgress client pod setup in EKS cluster full time.

Or else you can run command like this :

```
kubectl run postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image bitnami/postgresql --env="PGPASSWORD=<YOUR_PASSWORD>" --command -- psql --host <YOUR_HOSTNAME=SVC_NAME_OR_IP> -U <HERE_USERNAME>
```

make sure you are using the proper namespace name and service name.

Both are in the same VPC means you can direct connect over internal address or IP without creating an external service.

Comment: Thank you Harsh above command works, I would like to try the second way you suggested which is having a Postgres client setup, I have a Postgres client pod running, how do I access the RDS database without using kubectl ?

Comment: glad to here that @Kamal. i am not sure which PG client you are using if you are using cli you can do `exec` inside the client POD and connect to database.

Comment: You can also run the GUI PG client POD and use it connect with database. docker example : https://hub.docker.com/r/fenglc/pgadmin4

Comment: Thank you Harsh , I have tried the exec kubectl command it worked, let me try the third way you suggested the GUI PG client and I'll update you

Comment: Harsh, Is't possible to connect the private DB to PowerBI or an external tool?

Comment: yes it's possible but it should be in same network of VPC or you have to expose the private DB.